# Google analytics reporting API: measurements of last hour come very late

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We run a report on google analytics using [the reporting API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

```
Report metrics: ga:users ; ga:sessions; ga:pageViews
Report dimension: ga:date; ga:hour
```

The report is run every hour at the 30th minute to get the measurements of the last hour. Problem is we don't get the measurements all the time. Example: at 10:30 August 18 2017 we ran this report. This is the result:

```
Date            hour    users   sessions pageViews
Aug 18, 2017    05      457     445      1,236
Aug 18, 2017    06      1,243   1,242    3,480
Aug 18, 2017    07      3,908   3,956    10,637
Aug 18, 2017    08      2,890   2,693    6,161
Aug 18, 2017    09      0       0        0
```

Thus the measurements for 9 hour is not even there. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because of the [data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en). You don't experience it a lot due to the low session numbers, however 30 minutes is a short window to give GA to process data.

It is not uncommon to see reporting latencies of 3-8 hours.

Comment: It turns out that we have a license for google 360 with SLA guarantying 4 hours of data latency. Therefore we cannot expect the data to be available after 30 minutes. Thanks for your answer anyway @sdhaus.